# Codeigniter - Bootstrap Modal - passing data

Tags: php, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap

I am pretty new to Codeigniter and aiming to follow best practice as I learn. Currently I have a table that is generated via DB

**HTML Table**

```
<tr>
    <td>
      <a class="galName" href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" >
        <?php echo $gal['name']; ?>
      </a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <?php echo $gal['clientName']; ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**The Modal**

```
<div class="modal fade hide modal-creator" id="myModal" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
        <h3>Edit Gallery</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body"><?php echo form_open('url'); ?>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="span5">
            <?php print_r($galleryName); ?>
            <div class="control-group">
                <?php
                    $galleryName = array(
                        'id'            => 'galleryName',
                        'name'          => 'galleryName',
                        'placeholder'   => 'Gallery Name',
                        'required'      => 'required',
                    );
                    echo form_label('Gallery Name:', 'galleryName');
                    echo form_input($galleryName);
                ?>
            </div><!-- /control-group -->
       </div><!--/span5-->
   </div><!--/row-->
</div><!-- /modal-body -->

<div class="modal-footer">
    <!-- <p class="span3 resize">The following images are sized incorrectly. Click to edit</p> -->
    <a href="javascript:;" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
    <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-primary">Next</a>
</div>
```

The link calls a bootstrap modal where I want to pass the data for the selected gallery. I know that I can pass the data via jQuery, but is it possible to keep this modal in the MVC framework and if yes how does one go about calling the controller via the modal link?

Thanks so much on the help, and would be happy to accept any suggestions on resources for CodeIgniter. I am currently working through the Nettuts videos, though they are dated,and also  working through the user guide.

Comment: I generally put the modals in my view files.  Then whenever you want it to pop up(or whatever) you can use the event to load data on the modal form with an ajax request.

Comment: You should take a look at the [`remote` option](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals) of the modal, but all things considered, you will need JS/jQuery calling the framework via Ajax. What do you mean by "keeping the modal in the MVC framework" ?

Comment: @Sherbrow - just wanted to have the modal managed by controller, thus having access to my model, looks like Ajax is my go to on this.

Comment: If one of you could submit an answer would be happy to reward

Comment: @Bungdaddy did you maybe forgot to check some of the answers? :D or maybe our answers are not good for you could be np :)

Comment: yo @okok -- thanks for the heads up! You totally hooked me up on this answer. Thx!

Comment: @Bungdaddy oh yeah,i upvoted your question cause i was in trouble too with this, so glad to help you! have nice time mate!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i really think you are misunderstanding what modal is and what a controller is, you can't do this without ajax call:   `how does one go about calling the controller via the modal link`

what i usually do is to create a `view/modals/` folder then put there all my bootstrap modals so for example:

```
application/views/modals/my_modal_form.php
```

and that will looks as you shown, inside:

```
<div class="modal fade hide modal-creator" id="myModal" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
        <h3>Edit Gallery</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body"><?php echo form_open('url'); ?>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="span5">
            <?php print_r($galleryName); ?>
            <div class="control-group">
                <?php
                    $galleryName = array(
                        'id'            => 'galleryName',
                        'name'          => 'galleryName',
                        'placeholder'   => 'Gallery Name',
                        'required'      => 'required',
                    );
                    echo form_label('Gallery Name:', 'galleryName');
                    echo form_input($galleryName);
                ?>
            </div><!-- /control-group -->
       </div><!--/span5-->
   </div><!--/row-->
</div><!-- /modal-body -->

<div class="modal-footer">
    <!-- <p class="span3 resize">The following images are sized incorrectly. Click to edit</p> -->
    <a href="javascript:;" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
    <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-primary">Next</a>
</div>
```

so when i need that single modal i just load it inside the main controller view i want to show up that modal doing simply:

```
    <body>
    <?php echo $this->load->view('modals/my_modal_form'); ?>

    <tr>
    <td>
      <a class="galName" href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" >
        <?php echo $gal['name']; ?>
      </a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <?php echo $gal['clientName']; ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ajax is the way to go, i made a template library in wich i load all my modals so they can be called by javscript from anywhere on the app, then use ajax to submit the forms